# downloading multiple html5 generated images as a zip file

Tags: javascript

i am building a video hosting site. my video player generates video player screenshots by the onclick() function. i am also not sure if these images are deleted or stored after generating.

i have tried surfing around here trying to find a definitive assistance as i lack in javascript knowledge and it's so frustrating. please help me. ask me if you need any more info. :)

here is my html:

```
    <body>
      <div id="videoPanel">
        <div id="instructions">
          <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="720px" height="400px" controls preload="none" poster='' autoplay data-setup='{ "aspectRatio":"640:500", "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2] }'>
            <source src="/Custom-Video-Player/Masamune kun no Revenge - 07.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
          </video>
        </div>
        <button id="clicker" onclick="shoot()">Capture</button><br />
        <button id="download" onclick=""> download</button> <br/>
        <div id="output" style="display: inline-block; top: 4px; position: relative; border: dotted 1px #ccc; padding: 2px;"></div>

      </div>
    </body>
```

this is the javascript for the screenshot generation:

```
var videoId = 'my_video_1';
var scaleFactor = 0.25;
var snapshots = [];

var w = 720 * scaleFactor;
var h = 400 * scaleFactor;

function capture(video, scaleFactor) {
  if (scaleFactor == null) {
    scaleFactor = 1;
  }

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
  return canvas;
}

function shoot() {
    var video = document.getElementById(videoId);
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    var canvas = capture(video, scaleFactor);
    canvas.onclick = function () {
      window.open(this.toDataURL());
    };
    snapshots.unshift(canvas);
    output.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      output.appendChild(snapshots[i]);
    }
}
```

theres also a download button that i want to be able to function as such:

it will number all images in accordance to their generation in regard to the 'capture' button, put them all in a zip file and download when download is pressed.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Since you already have the data I would try using a lib like https://stuk.github.io/jszip/ - I don't think the browsers have a standardized way of helping you create zips.

Comment: how do i load the images onto the zip file? and number them? and then execute the download?

i am a beginner in javascript and its so complicated, coming from c++.